# Remove all elements from a Key value pair which are equal to elements in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have two list

```
static List<dynamic> List1= new List<dynamic>();
list<string> List2
```

List1 is `{Message='asdasd',Mobilenum=995955}`

i want to remove all elements from List1  if the value in list2 is there in list1?

I have done this but it is not working 
`List1.RemoveAll(c => list2.ToList().Exists(n => n.Mobilenum== c.Values));`

Comment: Why you use `dynamic`, you don't know the type at compile time?

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter if you are a beginner, don't use ``dynamic`` until you understand why you should use it.

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: You said `list2` is a `List` so why are you doing `ToList` on it? Also, is it `List2` or `list2`? What do you think `c.Values` would be? What do you think `n.Mobilenum` would be? It would probably be better if you called `c` `l1` and called `n` `l2` so you could remember what was in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
List1.RemoveAll(c => List2.Contains(c.Mobilenum));
```

But replace [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) with the real type. Normally you don't need to use it. If it's an anonymous type and you have to pass this list around,  consider to implement a new type with these properties.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a type instead of using `dynamic`:

```
public class MyType
{
   public string Message;
   public string Mobilenum;
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
var List1 = new List<MyType>();
// ...build your list 
var List2 = new List<string>();
// ...build your other list
var res = List1.Where(x => !List2.Contains(x.Mobilenum));
```

Avoid using Remove unless you're sure you want to throw away the information instead of just "filtering" it for a particular use.